# Why is the default value of a class member not taken when using pointers as opposed to when instantiating the object directly?

Tags: c++, oop, initialization

In the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Father
{
public:
    int a=11;
  void f(){ cout<<"f called"<<endl;}
};


int main(){

  Father *obj;
  cout <<obj->a<<endl; //I get a garbage value and the compiler issues a warning: 'obj' is used uninitialized in this function

  Father f;
  cout <<f.a<<endl; // it prints 11
return 1;
}
```

`cout <<obj->a<<endl;` is printing garbage value instead of the default value of 11, just like above . Aren't they suppose to print the same?
Why is the default value of a class member not taken when using pointers as opposed to when instantiating  the object directly?

Comment: When you create a pointer *obj it starts pointing to nothing and actually you need to create the object instead.

Comment: Because *obj points to nothing unless you assign it an instance of `Father`, e.g. :  Father *obj = new Father()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Aren't they suppose to print the same?

No. It's [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Given `Father *obj;`, `obj` is [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization#Notes) with indeterminate value,

> Default initialization of non-class variables with automatic and dynamic storage duration produces objects with indeterminate values

That means `obj` doesn't point to any valid object and dereference on it leads to [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), anything is possible. You need to make it pointing to a valid object, e.g.

```
Father f;
Father *obj = &f;
cout <<obj->a<<endl;
```

or

```
Father *obj = new Father;
cout <<obj->a<<endl;
delete obj;
```

`Father f;` performs [default-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) too. As a class type, `f.a` is initialized with value `11`.

> if T is a `non-POD (until C++11)` class type, the constructors are considered and subjected to overload resolution against the empty argument list. The constructor selected (which is one of the default constructors) is called to provide the initial value for the new object;

---

BTW: [Default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (as you write `int a=11;` in class `Father`) was supported from C++11, try to compile your code with C++11 (or above) mode.

Comment: what does UB mean?

Comment: Undefined Behavior I guess

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver Yes. Answer revised.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver before long you will come to fear the letters U and B

Comment: @ songyuanyao  is your last comment related to this warning I get, when running the code "warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11"? It is due to the default values. I really don't see what is the matter with default values

Comment: @ user4581301 why is so?

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver [Default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization), as you write `int a=11;` in class `Father`, was supported from C++11, and it seems you didn't compile with C++11 mode. Try to add compile option as the warning suggested.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the default value of a class member not taken when using pointers as opposed to when instantiating the object directly?

It is, but that's not what you're doing.

You have a `Father* obj` that doesn't actually point to anything.

It's a dangling pointer.

You're not allowed to use it.

Your program's behaviour is undefined.